# Google Chrome extension button pop-out: How to make it persistent

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, popup

I have a very simple Chrome extension which produces a bubble pop-out in the top-right of the screen. In the bubble I present the mobile version of our site.

Currently when the extension icon is clicked the bubble pops out and the mobile homepage loads. The user can click around within the bubble and use the mobile site as they wish.

However, once the user clicks outside the bubble is closes. Clicking again repeats the above process.

I wondered if there was a way to make the bubble pop-up/out persistent? So, instead of it disappearing when the user clicks elsewhere it stays loaded until the user clicks the extension icon again. This way the button acts as an on/off switch rather than a single event trigger.

Is this possible, and would someone mind directing me to the code which would help me do this?

Answer (score 1):

[As stated in the FAQs](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/faq.html#faq-persist-popups), this is not possible. However, [`chrome.windows.create`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/windows.html#method-create) may meet your needs.

Comment: Thanks @Pikadude - as I said. I am very new to this. Does the documentation for chrome.windows.create you've pointed me at mean you're suggesting I create a new, sized, browser for the pop-up instead?

Comment: @ChristopherJohnEggett: Yes, that's what I meant.